# Cannot install on tcolorbox on Red Hat 8 (checksums differ error)

Tags: tcolorbox, python, tlmgr, texlive-2019

I'm working off of RedHat 8, and I installed a slim version of LaTeX called TinyTeX.

I'm trying to install tcolorbox as it is needed to render Jupyter Notebooks as PDFs. However, whenever I try to install tcolorbox using `tlmgr` I get the following error:

```
tlmgr install tcolorbox
TeX Live 2019 is frozen forever and will no
longer be updated.  This happens in preparation for a new release.

If you're interested in helping to pretest the new release (when
pretests are available), please read https://tug.org/texlive/pretest.html.
Otherwise, just wait, and the new release will be ready in due time.

tlmgr: package repository http://mirrors.concertpass.com/tex-archive/systems/texlive/tlnet (not verified: valid signature with expired key)

[1/1, ??:??/??:??] install: tcolorbox [224k]
TLUtils::check_file: checksums differ for /tmp/I7g2FeBJNj/eqYkcsuSPH/tcolorbox.tar.xz:
TLUtils::check_file:   tlchecksum=071faa7ef1440eff776bc19ff6f7fc01250f3c2c7dd8ac916a408560e09fe5b4b2905d4502f0283c367c7a4fe4f503992adf99efe4a627afbc313ab4a9824d64, arg=59935197103e279b68a54dbe1b33936035b3073f1ce70ed70af8e405096d36df5d00a4b0bd583428211df3497b779e4b473359004c0d6aefbcdb4a398517a38b
TLUtils::check_file:   removing /tmp/I7g2FeBJNj/eqYkcsuSPH/tcolorbox.tar.xz, but saving copy in tlcheckfile_jzB1RZ3
TLPDB::_install_package: downloading did not succeed (check_file_and_remove failed)
tlmgr: package log updated: /opt/latex/.TinyTeX/texmf-var/web2c/tlmgr.log
```

I also tried installing tcolorbox using the zip file, however, I wasn't able to get tlmgr (or Python/Jupyter for that matter) to recognize tcolorbox had been installed from the zipped file.

#### UPDATE

I tried installing a different package, and I was able to successfully do that.

```
tlmgr install abc

TeX Live 2019 is frozen forever and will no
longer be updated.  This happens in preparation for a new release.

If you're interested in helping to pretest the new release (when
pretests are available), please read https://tug.org/texlive/pretest.html.
Otherwise, just wait, and the new release will be ready in due time.

tlmgr: package repository http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/systems/texlive/tlnet (not verified: valid signature with expired key)

[1/1, ??:??/??:??] install: abc [3k]
running mktexlsr ...
done running mktexlsr.
tlmgr: package log updated: /opt/latex/.TinyTeX/texmf-var/web2c/tlmgr.log
```

I also tried manually specifying different repositories using `tlmgr install --repository` but none of the ones I tried in the USA were working.

I also ran `tlmgr update --self --all` and then tried installing again, but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issues and after some searching around I tried changing the default repository to `ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2019/tlnet-final` (froze in 2019 because if you put the default it will go to version 2020 which I don't have atm). I then tried installing a bunch of things and it worked, including `tcolorbox`
Hope this helps. :)